# Angular2 after get petition, view doesn't display correctly

Tags: angular

After i do a GET petition on angular, the view doesn't update correctly.

The GET petition is used to fill a dropdown menu with options, my problem is that the dropdown display only the last option that was inserted in an array that contains all the allowed options for the user, although if i check the array in the console log, i can see all the elements in the array.

this is the html code:

```
<div class="dropdown center">
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="border-radius: 10px;">
        <i style="color: gray; margin: 5px;" class="fa fa-line-chart  " aria-hidden="true"></i> Oferta <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul *ngFor="let li of tabOferta" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a (click)="setChange(li,0)">{{li}}</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

and the typescript code:

```
tabOferta: string[] = [];
    this.indicadorService.getIndicadoresCatalogo().then(data => {

  this.zone.run(() => {
    for (let d of data) {
      switch (d.indicador) {
        case "oferta": {

          for (let clave of d.clave) {
            this.tabOferta.push(clave);
          }

          break;
        }
        case "demanda": {

          for (let clave of d.clave) {
            this.tabDemanda.push(clave);
          }

          break;
        }

        case "seguridad": {

          for (let clave of d.clave) {
            this.tabDemanda.push(clave);
          }


          break;
        }

        case "mercadotecnia": {

          for (let clave of d.clave) {
            this.tabDemanda.push(clave);
          }


          break;
        }
        case "comunidad": {

          for (let clave of d.clave) {
            this.tabDemanda.push(clave);
          }


          break;
        }
        case "accesibilidad": {

          for (let clave of d.clave) {
            this.tabDemanda.push(clave);
          }


          break;
        }

        default: {

          break;
        }
      }
    }

  });


});
```

what i'm missing? why only one option is displayed?

Comment: put your *ngFor on the li, not the ul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your *ngFor on the li not the ul element